# Can someone explain the use cases of esc_html?

Tags: security

I'm looking through _s (underscores) starter theme and see that they're using esc_html for nearly everything. Just an example from functions.php

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary', '_s' ),
) );

register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', '_s' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Add widgets here.', '_s' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
) );
```

My current understanding of esc_html is to use it when we output either data from the database or user input.

**Why escape the names of the menu and sidebar?**

It's only available to people that have access to the php files and it doesn't appear to be put into the db. I looked through the db and couldn't find anything related to the names, please correct me if I'm wrong.

**Is the underscores theme just being overly cautious about everything?**

Thanks

Comment: I think they are using it to internationalize the theme

Comment: @user3635808 For translation? That makes more sense. I was only looking at this from a security viewpoint and didn't consider anything else

Comment: Yes, for translation.

Comment: @user3635808 Ahhh, I didn't even catch that I was looking up `esc_html` instead of `esc_html__` - note the double underscores at the end.

Comment: @user3635808 That may make a good answer if you add in some research and examples :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[esc_html()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/#source) does two things:

1. [Checks for invalid UTF8 in a string.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_check_invalid_utf8/)
2. [Converts a number of special characters into their HTML entities](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_specialchars/), specifically deals with: &, <, >, “, and ‘.

Using it instead of `__()`, `_e` and other i18n functions protects your website from possible errors that can occur with unaware translators who may use text that contains (1) invalid UTF8 characters or (2) unwanted HTML code. Trust me, many translators will be tempted to use some 'nice' HTML tags like `<i>`, `<b>` etc, even worse, they won't close them correctly.

Comment: If you take a look at the [`esc_html__()` source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__/#source), you can see that this function only calls the [`esc_html()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/#source) function with the string translation, so what this post is explaining are the escape benefits and why the developers escaped these strings.

Answer (score 9):

```
esc_html__( string $text, string $domain = 'default' )
```

Retrieve the translation of $text and escapes it for safe use in HTML output.
so  `esc_html__()` use to make internationalize  as well as security purpose

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html_2

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Mac , Yes this should be accepted. `esc_html__` forbids the use of HTML in translated strings.

Answer (score 4):

The waters are muddy here. OP's question asks about **[esc_html()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/)**, but his code clearly uses **[esc_html__()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html_2)**. These are not the same. The accepted answer is wrong: it refers to **esc_html()**, which deals with safely escaping HTML blocks. Kanon Chowdhury's reply should be the accepted answer, because OP's code deals with the I18n aspects of the Underscores WordPress starter theme (which uses the **esc_html__()** function).

Answer (score 3):

[esc_html()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html) and [esc_html__()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html_2) are **NOT** the same functions. The main difference is,
esc_html() takes just one string and returns **an escaped HTML** string. On the other hand, esc_html__() takes 2 strings as parameters and returns **a translated and escaped** string.

The accepted answer is incorrect, indeed.

Comment: If you think that an answer is wrong (not just not useful), you are welcome to downvote it. Accepted answer status only means that the OP finds it good enough answer for his question, but do not indicate quality, or even general correctness, those are indicated by the number of upvotes.